# Problems importing own packages and modules

Tags: python, import, package

I am currently working on my first 'bigger' project where I want to separate some code. For me as a python newbie, it's pretty hard to get the imports right. I tried to use relative and absolute imports, but I can't get around all the different import errors. The project is currently structured like:

```
|- scripts
|   |-- etl
|   |    |-- etl.py
|   |-- model
|   |    |--model.py    
|   |-- ps
|   |    |--ps.py
|   |-- shared
|   |    |-- classes.py
|   |    |-- enums.py
|   |    |-- functions.py
|   |-- main.py
```

How can I import

1. classes.py and enums.py within the shared package
2. classes.py, enums.py and functions.py into etl.py, model.py, ps.py and main.py
3. classes from etl.py, model.py, ps.py into main.py

I searched the whole internet and could not make it work, but sadly could not make it so far (it could be because of the project structure as well. If there is a better structure which will make it work, I will change the structure!)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We can't say what's wrong if you don't show us the actual code, and the actual errors you're getting.

Comment: It sounds like you might have circular imports.  If module A imports module B, then module B cannot also import module A.